# Sort list by order of another one inocomplete and modified list

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have two lists, one of them is a subset modified subset of another. For example:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>(){ "A1", "A2", "A3" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "AA2", "B1", "B2", "AA1", "B3", "AA2" };
```

I want to sort the second list to have similar order like the first one, to look like this:

```
List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "AA1", "AA2", "AA3", "B1", "B2", "B3" };
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are modified the items?

Comment: in order to do this the "similar order" would have to be defined better... what's the rule?

Comment: From a list perspective, your second list is not a "subset" of the first one. The entries kinda look like the first one but they are not a subset. In your example, you would need some kind of logic to know that AA1 is a "subset" by definition of "A1". Then you could go through the first list and find the items that are somehow a subset of each item, and create a new list in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `list1` items are subsets (substrings) of `list2` items, you could do something like this using `Linq` and `string` functions. I'm not sure it is optimal, but works. Suggestions are welcome to improve the answer.

The idea is to find the index of `list1` item for corresponding `List2` item (if item not found then max index), then `Sort` based on index `ThenBy` by string/item.

```
    List<string> list1 = new List<string>(){ "A1", "A2", "A3" };
    List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "AA2", "B1", "B3", "AA1", "B2", "AA3" };


    var results = list2.Select(s=> 
    {
        var ind = list1.IndexOf(list1.Find(f=> s.Contains(f)));

        return new 
        { 
            index= ind==-1? int.MaxValue : ind, // assign max value if item is not found to place in the end in order. 
            item =s 
        };

    }).OrderBy(o=>o.index).ThenBy(o=>o.item).Select(s=>s.item);
```

**Output**

```
AA1
AA2
AA3
B1
B2
B3
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gyXW78)